# Updating Google Play Services

Tags: android, google-play-services

ALL,

I'm trying to develop an Android application. The application will use the GeoLocation which is based on the Google Play Services.

I also have a phone for testing (Samsung with Android 4.2.2). When checking things with Eclipse I see that the device has this service but its version is not the same as the application was developed with.

So I push the code which should go to Google Store and update the service to bring the proper version on the device. Now this device does not have a service only a WiFi (meaning its just a piece of hardware, not the phone).

Now when I ran this code it goes to the Google Store and it continuously tries to find the appropriate .apk.

The code I pushed is as follows:

```
    int res = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable( getApplicationContext() );
    if( res != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS )
    {
        try
        {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog( res, this, RQS_GooglePlayServices ).show();
        }
        catch( Exception e )
        {
            Utils.displayErrorDialog( this, e.getMessage() );
        }
    }
```

What am I missing? It should just be straight update.

Thank you.

Comment: did you update the google play services of your device?

Comment: @DevCarlsberg, this is what I'm trying to do programmatically. The piece of code I posted should ask the user to update it by going to the Google Store. Now it does start the Store application and then it just showing the wait cursor.

Answer (score 0):

My problem sounds related.  I have installed Foursquare on my Android (Jelly Bean) and when I launch Foursquare it pops-up with, you must upgrade Google Play (sounds like what you are trying to do in your App).  I then click on the button and it launches the GP Store to upgrade.  The upgrade stops progressing at 54% completion.  Consistently -- after multiple times.  I am suspect of memory size, as my Android is SLOOOOOWWWW, under powered and low on memory.